# What is difference between create object with init and () in Swift

Tags: swift, init

```
class A {

    private var value: Int

    init(value: Int) {
        self.value = value
    }
}
```

We have class A and what is the difference between I create this object by using **A.init(value: 5)** and **A(value: 5)**? Thanks

Comment: None, this is the exact same thing, just better autocomplete with init()

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is no functional difference between the two. Both styles will call the same initializer and produce the same value.

---

Most style guides that I've seen prefer to leave out the explicit `.init`-part in favor of the shorter `A(value:)` syntax — that also resembles the constructor syntax in many other languages.

That said, there are some scenarios where it's useful to be able to explicitly reference the initializer. For example:

- when the type can be inferred and the act of initialization is more important than the type being initialized. Being able to call `return .init(/* ... */)` rather than `return SomeComplicatedType(/* ... */)` or `let array: [SomeComplicatedType] = [.init(/* ... */), .init(/* ... */)]`
- when passing the initializer to a higher order function, being able to pass `"something".map(String.init)` rather than `"something".map({ String($0) })`

Again, it's a matter of *style*.

Comment: I have the same answer on my mind but when work with some ObjC static method sometime only can use init syntax.

    @@interface Order : NSObject

    + (Order *)orderWithOrderId:(NSString *)orderId total:(int)total;

    @@end

This function Xcode force me to using init syntax so make me thing about the difference between them.

Comment: @Alan can you give a concrete example?

Comment: @ interface Order : NSObject

+ (Order *)orderWithOrderId:(NSString *)orderId total:(int)total;

@ end

Comment: @Alan I'm able to use `Order(orderId: "abc", total: 3)` just fine with that Objective-C definition.

Comment: maybe it is related swift 2.3. anyway thanks for your replay let me have more confidence on this topic